# Image to coordinate system

Tags: image-processing, image

May I kindly ask you to teach me how to align the symmetry axis (in blue) of the attached picture along the Ox and/or Oy axis. The axis of symmetry is slightly off (rotated to the right).
In other words I am already able to extract the points of the edge and plot them. However I don't know how to extract the points of intersection of the symmetry axis  with the edge and then to position them (both) either on the Ox or on the Oy. 
Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Try taking any two points along that line, computing the angle to the x-axis, and using that in `ImageRotate`.

Comment: If you can show how you drew the picture, it would be a lot easier to answer your question.

Comment: Hi Bill! Thank you!